# How does the compiler deduce array size when defined as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, reference, template-argument-deduction

I am wondering how, in the following piece of code, the compiler deduces the `arrsize` template argument from the `T (&arr)[arrsize]` function argument. For example, when I pass a 4-element array to it, without mentioning the number 4 in my call to the function, it correctly determines the `arrsize` argument to be 4. However, if I pass the array normally (not as a reference to array), that is, if I change `T (&arr)[arrsize]` to `T arr[arrsize]`, it requires me to explicitly provide the `arrsize` argument in the template argument list.

```
template <class T, int arrsize> void bubblesort(T (&arr)[arrsize], int order=1)
{
    if (order==0) return;
    bool ascending = (order>0);
    int i,j;
    for (i=arrsize; i>0; i--)
        for (j=0; j<i-1; j++)
            if (ascending?(arr[j]>arr[j+1]):(arr[j]<arr[j+1])) swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
}
```

So my question is:

1. How does the compiler figure out the value of the `arrsize` argument automatically when I pass to the function a reference to an array? (What is the mechanism?)
2. Why can the compiler not do the same if I pass the array normally? (by normally I mean without using the reference symbol)

Comment: `Type arr[arrsize]` come from the C :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It can deduce the size because the size is known at compile-time within the calling context. If you have `int a[4]`, and you write `bubblesort(a)`, then the compiler uses the fact that the type of `a` is `int[4]` to deduce `arrsize` as 4. If you try to do `bubblesort(p)` when `p` has type `int*`, deduction will fail and a compile error will result.
2. If you write `T arr[arrsize]` as the parameter instead of `T (&arr)[arrsize]`, then the compiler will automatically rewrite the declaration as `T* arr`. Since `arrsize` no longer occurs in the signature, it can't be deduced.

Comment: And 2. is because C.

Comment: To be precise, because old C. I think C11 now has a similar mechanism for VLA's, but that's irrelevant to C++11. The two languages have diverged  over the last 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

`T arr[arrsize]` as a formal argument decays to just `T* arr`, where the `arrsize` is ignored completely (as indeed is the array nature of that argument).