# Could someone explain this syntax? T (&arr)[arrsize] vs T& arr[arrsize]

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, casting

This is in reference to the first formal parameter in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952603/how-does-the-compiler-deduce-array-size-when-defined-as-a-template-parameter) question.

> NOTE: `T` and `arrsize` are passed as template parameters here.

`T (&arr)[arrsize]` appears to be some sort of cast, but to what I am not sure. `&arr` is not a typename, it's just a formal parameter name with a reference symbol next to it. Why wouldn't one just put `T* arr[]`? Furthermore, I didn't think casting in a formal parameter list, or coercion, was possible in a language that implements function overloading. (i.e., introduces ambiguity in function calls). I suppose template functions introduce useful ambiguity, so is casting allowed in this context -- assuming two template functions don't have the same signature, barring the casting?

When this template is instantiated, what type does this argument become? Is it a pointer or a reference to a static array; simply `T*`; or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T (&arr)[arrsize]
```

When used in a function parameter declares a variable named `arr` that is a reference to an array of type `T` with the size `arrsize`.  This is a way to pass an array to a function and not have it decay into a pointer.  You can use the array in the function just like you would in the scope you declared it in.

```
T& arr[arrsize]
```

Is an array of references which is not allowed per the standard.  It should be a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

`T& arr[arrsize]`: *arr* is an array (of size *arraysize*) of `T&`'s (**Which is illegal in C++**)

`T (&arr)[arrsize]`: *arr* is a reference to an array (of size *arraysize*) of `T`'s

Comment: array of ```T```s probably